# Contar a quantidade de registros do meu IF

Tags: sql-server, query, if, count

**IF(count(UCID)>1,count(UCID),'0')**, ele me traz aproximadamente 500 linhas de registro, sendo números de 2 acima, quero poder fazer um COUNT nesse IF para apresentar esses 500 em uma coluna a parte.
Alguém tem uma sugestão?
Agradeço desde já.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a coluna "Rechamada" é meu IF e esta ai com 10 linhas de resultado, quero saber como mostrar em outra coluna o resultado 10 (coluna "QTD de Registros").

Comment: Não entendi seu problema. Poderia mostrar um exemplo de como seria a sua saída desejada?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado editei colocando uma imagem veja se ajuda a compreensão.

Comment: Ué, eu abri a imagem no celular, mas agora não consigo mais... Enfim, não penso em nenhum jeito mais elegante, mas tenho uma proposta...

Comment: seria tipo um cont.valores do excel mas no SQL, algo equivalente.

Answer (score 1):

Pegue sua consulta, vamos chamá-la de `Q_ORIGINAL`. Declare ela em uma [CTE](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expression).

Para se acostumar com CTEs, ele é uma alternativa a subqueries que eu acho muito elegante. Vamos começar daqui, que obtém exatamente a mesma resposta que a `Q_ORIGINAL`:

```
WITH q AS (
    Q_ORIGINAL
)
SELECT
    *
FROM q
```

Com CTEs, podemos fazer algumas brincadeiras interessantes; por exemplo, usar CTE que depende de outra CTE:

```
WITH q AS (
    Q_ORIGINAL
), conta_q AS (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) as n
    FROM
        q
)
SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT n FROM conta_q) as QTD
FROM
    q
```

Note que isso vai adicionar uma coluna nova com a quantidade para todas as linhas de resultado.

Comment: Cara muito bem pensado, porem, é bem mais difícil fazer aqui, pois estou em um software de B.I onde meu IF é uma expressão, uma linha, um pequeno trecho de calculo, pensei que fosse mais simples como "count(if(count(ucid)..."  mas acho que nao vai rolar.

Comment: É uma pena não funcionar... Não consegui pensar em outra estratégia que resolvesse